# How to initialize the following folder schema to work with Git?

Tags: git

I have the follow folder schema that is like a mirror of a work process I am implementing.

I would like to know if it is correct the follow sentences to initialize each folders in the schema:

```
User-1 (programmer) -> Git clone .... From Test
User-n (programmer) -> Git clone .... From Test

Test  -> Git init --bare .... To Assembla

Web_site -> Git clone .... from Assembla
```

[image]

Comment: Looks good, but one cannot be sure not having worked with it. You could try this with dummy projects and to check if it satisfies your needs or not. Just have all users clone or track what they have to, then imitate some work.